# Why Bulletproofs protocol needs to raise $u$ to power $x$ in Protocol 1?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

The [paper on the Bulletproofs Zero-Knowledge proof protocol](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1066.pdf) states in paragraph 3:

> In Protocol 1 the element $u$ is raised to a verifier chosen power $x$ to ensure that the extracted vectors $a, b$ from Protocol 2 satisfy $\langle a, b\rangle =c$.

I can't make sense of this.

I guess it is because the scalar $u$ is not given in the relation, thus the value $P'$ can be computed incorrectly. Am I right?

Also I wonder assuming $u$ is public and given in the corresponding relation, if we can omit this step and directly run Protocol 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the authors give an [anwser](https://github.com/AdamISZ/from0k2bp/issues/4):

> Protocol 2 proves the following statement: "given a point P, there
>   exist vectors a and b such that P = aG + bH + *G". This problem
>   is that this statement isn't very useful. If I give you a point P,
>   it's nice to know that I can deconstruct it into some sort of inner
>   product thing, but in practice you typically know what  should
>   be, and you want a proof that it's the correct thing. We'll call the
>   statement being proved here Statement 1.
>
> So the statement we really want is "Given P and c, there exist vectors
>   a and b such that P = aG + bH and c = ". Same as above, but I've
>   moved the actual inner product "out of hiding" by taking it out of P
>   and making it explicit. Call this Statement 2.
>
> The obvious way prove Statement 2, which we want, given only a proof
>   system for Statement 1, which we have, would be for the verifier to
>   compute "P' = P + cG" and ask for a proof of Statement 1 on P'. This
>   doesn't work, because a malicious prover could simply prove Statement
>   1 on a point P', then choose c to be whatever he wanted and provide c,
>   P = P' - cG to a verifier.
>
> There are a few ways to prevent this. The tactic chosen in the paper
>   is to force the prover to choose P before he learns what G is. Then he
>   can't set P = P' - cG; for a given P' this is either true or it isn't!
>   Instead, the prover is forced to choose P' = P + cG, which is exactly
>   what we want him to.
>
> So how can we force the prover to choose P before knowing G? Easy,
>   hash P to get a new value x and replace G with xG.